# Calculate Average of Text Value Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to calculation average of text value MySQL, usually we are calculation by this way I guess

```
select AVG(clmn_name) from tbl_name
```

But its worked when value of column is integer[number] like 5 or 10 or 99, then its giving you output average of this 3 value

But when there is Text value like, John, Kerry, Michel, Teddy, its possible to get average of this?

I mean if there is 50 row with John, 10 with Kerry, 2 with Michel & 80 with Teddy so from all of them Teddy has biggest number how can I get Teddy by MySQL, Please help me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you don't want the average, you want the name with the highest count?

Comment: I have solve its using MAX Function of MySQL, but thanks for your fast replay...